# Transforming to GPS coordinates using projections with osgeo with Python

Tags: python, datum, osgeo

I am trying to transform a shapefile and its datum to GPS (EPSG Projection 4326 - WGS 84) but I get very different result on Google Earth, I write:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

file_name = 'POIS.shp'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataset = driver.Open(file_name)
layer = dataset.GetLayer()
in_spacial_ref = layer.GetSpatialRef()
print (in_spacial_ref)
out_spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
out_spatial_ref.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
coord_trans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(in_spacial_ref, out_spatial_ref)

x, y = 734150.2990000024, 6465754.138
x_gps, y_gps, _ = coord_trans.TransformPoint(x,y, 0)

# Google earth  3° 26.139'E, 45° 17.418'N, 
print (x_gps, y_gps)
# 3.435642392921613 45.290299860385545
```

print (in_spacial_ref) gives me:

```
PROJCS["RGF_1993_Lambert_93",
    GEOGCS["GCS_RGF_1993",
        DATUM["Reseau_Geodesique_Francais_1993",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",700000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",6600000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",3.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",44.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",49.0],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.5],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

How can I get the exact values of Google Earth? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Argh! I got it, Google Earth writes result on degrees, minutes although they write (on the preferences) decimal minutes it is not decimal!

0.435642*60/100 = 0.2613852 and
0.290299860385545*60/100 = 0.174179916231327